# Mod division of two integers

Tags: java, division, modular-arithmetic

I keep getting the error "The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) Integer, Integer" I am not quite sure why this is happening. I thought that since modular division cannot return decimals that having integer values would be alright.

This is happening within a method in a program I am creating. 
The code is as follows:

```
    public void addToTable(Integer key, String value)
{
    Entry<Integer, String> node = new Entry<Integer, String>(key, value);
    if(table[key % tableSize] == null)
        table[key % tableSize] = node;
}
```

The method is unfinished but the error occurs at

```
    if(table[key % tableSize] == null)
```

and

```
    table[key % tableSize] = node;
```

any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Suspect @durron597 is correct and you're using < 1.5, so go with the answers below.

Comment: In Java 1.5 and 1.6, I can get Integer % Integer to compile successfully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could get some sample `Integer % Integer` code to compile successfully in Java 1.5 and 1.6, but not in 1.4.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Integer x = 10;
   Integer y = 3;
   System.out.println(x % y);
}
```

This is the error in 1.4:

```
ModTest.java:7: operator % cannot be applied to java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer
       System.out.println(x % y);
                            ^
```

The most reasonable explanation is that because [Java introduced autoboxing and autounboxing in 1.5](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/auto-boxing-and-unboxing-in-java-be.html), you must be using a Java compiler from before 1.5, say, 1.4.

Solutions:

- Upgrade to Java 1.5/1.6/1.7.
- If you must use 1.4, use `Integer.intValue()` to extract the `int`
  values, on which you can use the `%` operator.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me.

```
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(10);
Integer y = Integer.valueOf(3);

int z = x % y;

System.out.println(z);
```

No problems. Output:

```
1
```

What error are you getting? What version of Java are you using? It seems that you're using Java below 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting here is called unboxing, the auto-conversion of an object to a primitive type (going the other way is autoboxing).

The Java docs have this to say:

---

The Java compiler applies unboxing when an object of a wrapper class is:

- Passed as a parameter to a method that expects a value of the corresponding primitive type.
- Assigned to a variable of the corresponding primitive type.

---

So one possibility is that you're *not* doing one of those things and, although it appears at first glance that you're neither passing your mod expression to a method nor assigning it to a variable, it's valid, at least in Java 6:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer x = 17;
        Integer y = 5;
        System.out.println (x % y);
        String [] z = new String[10];
        z[x % y] = "hello";
    }
}
```

The other possibility is that you're using a pre Java 5 environment, where autoboxing and unboxing was introduced.

Best bet in that case is probably to be explicit and use `Integer.intValue()` to get at the underlying `int`.

However you may also want to consider using an `int` (not `Integer`) for the key and only boxing it up at the point where you *need* to (when you add it to an `Entry`). It may well be faster to use the primitive type, though you should of course benchmark it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the Integers to ints, then run `%`.

```
if(table[key.intValue() % tableSize.intValue()] == null)
        table[key.intValue() % tableSize.intValue()] = node;
```